# Disable Sorting for all Columns - dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.10. I want to disable sorting for all Columns when a checkbox is clicked (on) and wise versa. This is to be done after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You cannot! The only way to change the sorting capabilities completely is to set `ordering: false` and reinitialize the table.

However, with some jQuery magic you can loop through each `<th>`, store the events, `unbind()` and then reattach the stored events to their `<th>`'s when sorting is needed again. This is not a trivial task. There is three events bound to each column : `click`, `keypress` and `selectStart.dt`. Furthermore, each event has to be deep cloned since they are destroyed when they are `unbind()`.

Here is an example to do this when a checkbox is clicked :

```js
var storedEvents;
$('#sort').change(function() {
 if (!$(this).is(':checked') && storedEvents) {
   $('#example thead th').each(function(index, th) {
      for (var event in storedEvents[index]) {
         $(th).bind(event, storedEvents[index][event][0])
      }
   })  
 } else {
   storedEvents = [];
   $('#example thead th').each(function() {
      storedEvents.push( $.extend( true, {}, $._data( this, "events" ) ));
      $(this).unbind();
   })  
 }   
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s7uzzkcg/**